# Android APK Expansion

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I had everything working and then I needed to upload a new version of the resources in the obb.  I upped the version number in my Manifest to 3, I made a zip of the resources and named it main.3..obb and uploaded it just like I did for the first one.  I updated the Now when I try to download it I get this:

```
I/LicenseChecker(971): Binding to licensing service.
I/LicenseChecker(971): Calling checkLicense on service for <package>
I/LicenseChecker(971): Start monitoring timeout.
I/LicenseChecker(971): Received response.
I/LicenseChecker(971): Clearing timeout.
W/LicenseValidator(971): Error contacting licensing server.
```

I can't seem to get any more information about what went wrong!  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From others' experiences, you need to wait several hours for google to prepare the files. Reference: [Error contacting licensing server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916922/error-contacting-licensing-server)